# How do I find the last logged system boot and shutdown times?

Tags: boot, shutdown, logging, events

I'm a Rails developer working on a web application on Ubuntu Server 10.04. Due to internal requirements, I was asked to find the last 10 system boot and shutdown times... I have no clue where to find these details. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 53):

Use the [`last`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?last) command.

```
last -x | grep shutdown
last -x | grep reboot
```

You can pipe this to the [`head`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head) to read the last *n* instances. For example, in your case:

```
last -x | grep shutdown | head -n 10
```

You also should set

```
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes
```

in the `/etc/default/bootlogd` file (it could be No by default).

Comment: great answer, I add | tail -10

Comment: I have no `/etc/default/bootlogd` on my Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: More on [how to enable bootlogd](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd), which is not necessary as of Debian Wheezy ([i.e. as of Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on) -- or so seems likely).

Answer (score 3):

For a GUI method you can use `hardinfo` as described here: [Does Ubuntu have a "device manager" equivalent? And what is an easy way to access USB drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887264/does-ubuntu-have-a-device-manager-equivalent-and-what-is-an-easy-way-to-acces/887314#887314).

Under the section `Boots` you will see this:

[image: Hardinfo boot log.png]

Installation is straight forward using:

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

Comment: For some reason it displays only the latest boot in my case

Comment: @VadimKotov When you type `hardinfo` from the command line do you see errors as in this bug report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hardinfo/+bug/1473142

Comment: Nope, it displays only this: `Gtk-Message: 17:54:10.696: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`