# What logfile contains time of startup and shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, log, logout

I would like to analyze my PC usage and therefore have a list of when I shut down my laptop or alternatively when I logged out from my account in the last month. Is there any logfile containing this information and if yes, where can I find it?

Using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Most logs are in `/var/log`, check `/var/log/user.log[.X]` and see if that's what you need.

Comment: [*Cough*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37132/how-do-i-find-the-last-logged-system-boot-and-shutdown-times)

Comment: @Mr.Lee - Nasty cough you have there... :D - much better than `possibly duplicate...`

Comment: Thank you, guys! This is indeed a duplicate of the above mentioned question.