# Ubuntu Trusty - corresponding Debian release? Wheezy or Squeeze?

Tags: debian, versions, release-management

I want to install [**Dotdeb**](http://www.dotdeb.org) on `Ubuntu trusty, Release 14.04` and I was wondering which [version of the available packages for Debian](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) I should choose. `Wheezy` or `Squeeze`?

Comment: Neither of them seems to fit, but If you have to pick one of those, it would definitely be Wheezy. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/which-ubuntu-version-is-equivalent-to-debian-squeeze/445496#445496

Comment: check [Which Ubuntu version is equivalent to Debian Squeeze?][1] Safest to test a virtual machine first.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/which-ubuntu-version-is-equivalent-to-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 2):

`squeeze` is way too old for Ubuntu 14.04. If you must, use `wheezy`. I'd recommend against it altogether and ask the maintainer for a Ubuntu release.