# Is it safe to install debian packages on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, debian

I have a new version of a package that is only avaliable on debian repos.

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 3.19.0-79-generic #87~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 21 18:12:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Current package:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ifenslave
ii  ifenslave                           2.4ubuntu1.2                      amd64          configure network interfaces for parallel routing (bonding)
```

This [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) suggests the process doesn't work in reverse but is this safe for a direct installation from the deb package? Is there a process to get package version migrated to ubuntu? [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511264/ubuntu-trusty-corresponding-debian-release-wheezy-or-squeeze) suggests I should ask the maintainer.

The package I would like to install the wheezy package [ifenslave-2.6](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/ifenslave-2.6/download) and when I do a manual `dpkg -i` after removing the previous version it appears to be installed correctly. Is this likely to break in the future or cause instability in my system? Is there anything I can do further to validate?

Comment: As you know Ubuntu is Debian-based. I have tried a few Debian packages with no problem. And when it comes to system stability, it's always a good idea to back up your computer regularly. Or alternatively, when things go wrong, start by removing untrusted deb/ppa from your source.list one by one

Comment: I will be adding it to my own trusted ppa as a one off. Is there anything inherently unstable about installing a deb not specifically packaged for Ubuntu? The last question didn't really go into why it might be unstable, just that it might be difficult to pin down the root cause of issues.