# show debian distribution of ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

how to show Debian distribution name used in ubuntu?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

no debian release name here

Comment: You are on a ubuntu disro and you are looking for Debian. Strange

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/445496/15811

Comment: I don't think any Ubuntu release perfectly matches up with any Debian release (*which I fear most newbies will misunderstand*).  Many of my Ubuntu packages (I use *development* which currently is *focal*, but I'll bump later in the month to *g??*) and a large number of packages are later than my equivalent Debian *sid/testing* box. Yes some version numbers for some packages match, but Ubuntu patches many from upstream git itself, not from Debian so it varies on package. Others do go into Debian to flow thru to Ubuntu, but it's not simple.

Comment: $ cat /etc/debian_version