# How to check which underlaying Debian version my Ubuntu release does use?

Tags: debian, lsb-release

I see `lsb_release` is mentioned below.

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/how-to-check-debian-version/

Unfortunately, it may not work on all Debian based systems; for example, on a stock Ubuntu 20.04.2, it returns the following:

```
$ lsb_release
No LSB modules are available.
```

Is there any other way for me to find out which version of Debian my current Ubuntu installation is based on?

Comment: This is not the site for all Debian based system. Which official flavors and version of Ubuntu are you running? Try `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: It is better to ask at [linux.se]. It seems to be off-topic here.

Comment: I also get `No LSB modules are available.` on stock Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Comment: I have offered a bold edit to this question to keep it on-topic for this website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Debian version are the different Ubuntu versions based on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could search for /etc/debian_version, even display it to get your answer.

```
    cat /etc/debian_version
```

Comment: Odd how easy this is to do but difficult find. TLDR - 23.04 is bookworm/sid

Answer (score 0):

On Debian and Ubuntu (and maybe derivative) systems, `/etc/debian_version` exists. Looking in `/etc/apt/sources.list` should show you where the packages were installed from.

It is possible that someone installed the system and then later completely changed `/etc/apt/sources.list` (which would most likely break the system at next upgrade, but…). In this case you could look at where specific installed packages were obtained from with:

```
$ apt policy <packagename>
```

The proper way however is for package `lsb-release` to be installed so that the command you used gives proper output.